# AttributeError when importing flask-SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am following [this](https://codeburst.io/jwt-authorization-in-flask-c63c1acf4eeb) tutorial to build a JWT based authentication system.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'd0cad49580952003e6ae01499c7bb190a4b4f9a5babd866f47064707f7b78506'

api = Api(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()


import resources, models

api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

models.py:

```
from app import db


class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, password, email):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email

    @classmethod
    def find_by_username(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

resources.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from models import UserModel


class UserRegistration(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('name', help='This field cannot be blank', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('email', help='This field cannot be blank', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('password', help='This field cannot be blank', required=True)

        data = parser.parse_args()

        if UserModel.find_by_username(data['name']):
            return {'message': 'User {} already exists'.format(data['name'])}

        new_user = UserModel(
            name=data['name'],
            password=data['password'],
            email=data['email']
        )
        try:
            new_user.save_to_db()
            return {
                'status': 'User {} was created'.format(data['username'])}

        except:
            return {'message': 'Something went wrong'}, 500
```

When I run app.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python\PycharmProjects\vumonic\app.py", line 19, in <module>
    import resources, models
  File "G:\python\PycharmProjects\vumonic\resources.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import UserModel
  File "G:\python\PycharmProjects\vumonic\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "G:\python\PycharmProjects\vumonic\app.py", line 21, in <module>
    api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')
AttributeError: module 'resources' has no attribute 'UserRegistration'
```

This error dissapears when I remove `from models import UserModel` from resources.py.

I cannot figure out the reason for the error.

I am using Flask==1.1.2, Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4 and Flask-RESTful==0.3.8

This is the first time Iam developing an API so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a circular dependency - app imports models which imports app.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov I tried removing import models, but it has no effect on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are facing circular import issue.

When Python imports a module, it checks the module registry to see if the module was already imported. If the module was already registered, Python uses that existing object from cache. The module registry is a table of modules that have been initialized and indexed by module name. This table can be accessed through `sys.modules`.

If it was not registered, Python finds the module, initializes it if necessary, and executes it in the new module's namespace.

to know more about circular import you can read the article:

https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

https://www.stefaanlippens.net/circular-imports-type-hints-python.html

this tutorial of Miguel Grinberg is a life savior
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH-8oLHUyDc&t=3205s

Comment: It was indeed acircular import issue but it wasn't caused because of importing flask ,as flask is a library and i think it is the only way to import it.

Comment: i forgot to edit the description. i had to answer similar question where his script name was 'flask'. forgot to eliminate the line, i hope your issue has been resolved.